# Can't Access Current Wordpress Web Pages

Tags: wordpress, apache, centos

I'm uploading my website to Apache on CentOS on Google Cloud and I can't access all of my existing web pages, I get the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /home was not found on this server.
```

However, when I create a new page I can access it no problem.

I've uploaded my files again, and double checked all the database stuff checked out and I've checked my .htaccess file.  I can't figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the .htaccess file contains the following content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You should also check if `.htaccess` is actually working. The easiest way to check this is to intentionally break it, by adding some text to the file. If .htaccess is working you should get an `Internal Server Error` page.